# String v Float in Python 3

Tags: python, string

easier version

```
totport443 = "13.2"
totport80 = "55.9"

float (totport443)
float (totport80)

total = totport443 + totport80

print (total)
```

Output  13.255.9

Why isn't this addition instead of concatanation

Comment: `TIntranetPort80 = 0.0` does not mean anything you put in it will be a float. you need to explicitly cast your value using `float(TIntranetPort80)`

Comment: I did this as well and am doing it as we speak  It still concatenates as a string..??

Comment: TotIntranetArrayPort443 = line.split()
                    TIntranetPort443 = TotIntranetArrayPort443[5]
                    float(TIntranetPort443)
                    float (TIntranetPort80)
                    TIntranet = TIntranetPort443 + TIntranetPort80
                    print (TIntranet)
     
19.732.9  

should  be 19.7 + 32.9 = 52.6

Comment: `float(TIntranetPort80)` *returns*  a float value. you would for instance use : `TIntranet = float(TIntranetPort443) + float(TIntranetPort80)` or `TIntranetPort80 = float(TotIntranetArrayPort80[5])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
float (totport443)
float (totport80)
```

The above lines don't do anything. You convert those values to floats and then throw the floats away because you don't do anything with them. The original values remain strings. You want:

```
totport443 = float(totport443)
totport80  = float(totport80)
```

Comment: I love you.  I am so new at this.  As soon as I saw it I knew what I had missed.  Right I wasn't doing anything... now I am.  Need to think like this more...